# animate svg using fill

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

how to make animation using path SVG of illustrator. I got SVG code (path) from illustrator cs6, after I finished making the object there.

for animation, i'm using css3 (animation) without javascript. so, i put svg code into html file, and animation of object, its working, but my problem is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <style>
            .map {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #FFF;
              stroke-dasharray: 5000;
              stroke-dashoffset: 5000;
            }
            .animate {
              -webkit-animation: dash 100s linear alternate;
              animation: dash 100s linear alternate;
              -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            }
            @keyframes dash {
                from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 5000; fill: #FFF !important;
                }
                to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0; fill: #FFF !important;
                }
            } 
            @-webkit-keyframes dash {
                from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 5000;
                }
                to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                }
            }                   
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: black;">

<svg id="ps4" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" viewBox="0 0 600 318" enable-background="new 0 0 600 318" xml:space="preserve">

    <path class="map animate" d="M5.831,7.433C9.023,6.9,13.355,6.444,18.599,6.444c6.537,0,11.325,1.521,14.365,4.256
        c2.736,2.432,4.484,6.156,4.484,10.792c0,4.712-1.368,8.361-3.952,11.021C30,36.238,24.3,38.138,17.991,38.138
        c-2.128,0-4.104-0.152-5.472-0.38v20.293H5.831V7.433z M12.519,32.362c1.064,0.304,3.268,0.456,5.472,0.456
        c7.98,0,12.845-3.952,12.845-10.944c0-6.917-4.788-10.185-12.084-10.185c-2.964,0-5.092,0.228-6.232,0.456V32.362z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M46.263,7.509c3.42-0.684,8.208-1.064,12.769-1.064c7.068,0,11.629,1.292,14.821,4.18c2.508,2.28,4.028,5.776,4.028,9.729
        c0,6.765-4.256,11.249-9.652,13.073v0.152c3.952,1.444,6.308,5.168,7.524,10.413c1.672,7.22,2.888,12.084,3.952,14.061h-6.84
        c-0.836-1.444-1.976-5.853-3.42-12.237c-1.52-6.992-4.256-9.729-10.26-9.957h-6.232v22.193h-6.688V7.509z M52.951,30.842h6.764
        c7.068,0,11.553-3.876,11.553-9.729c0-6.688-4.788-9.5-11.781-9.577c-3.268,0-5.472,0.304-6.536,0.608V30.842z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M93.838,6.825v51.227H87.15V6.825H93.838z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M148.636,35.554c-0.456-7.068-0.912-15.733-0.836-22.042h-0.228c-1.748,5.929-4.028,12.845-6.536,19.685l-8.893,24.549
        h-5.244l-8.133-24.397c-2.508-7.221-4.484-13.833-5.852-19.837h-0.228c-0.228,6.309-0.456,14.821-0.988,22.573l-1.368,21.965
        h-6.309l3.572-51.227h8.437l8.74,24.853c2.128,6.156,3.8,12.237,5.092,17.557h0.228c1.292-5.168,3.116-11.173,5.472-17.633
        l9.121-24.777h8.437l3.192,51.227h-6.537L148.636,35.554z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M174.018,41.938l-5.244,16.113h-6.917l17.481-51.227h7.905l17.481,51.227h-7.068l-5.473-16.113H174.018z M190.814,36.77
        l-5.016-14.745c-1.14-3.344-1.9-6.384-2.66-9.349h-0.228c-0.684,3.04-1.52,6.156-2.508,9.272l-5.017,14.821H190.814z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M228.357,58.051V6.825h7.373l16.341,25.841c3.724,6.08,6.764,11.477,9.196,16.721l0.152-0.076
        c-0.608-6.841-0.76-13.073-0.76-20.978V6.825h6.232v51.227h-6.688l-16.265-25.993c-3.572-5.701-6.993-11.553-9.577-17.101
        l-0.228,0.076c0.38,6.46,0.532,12.617,0.532,21.129v21.889H228.357z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M304.89,34.034h-19.837v18.545h22.193v5.472h-28.882V6.825h27.741v5.472h-21.053v16.265h19.837V34.034z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M354.746,55.771c-2.965,1.064-8.816,2.813-15.733,2.813c-7.752,0-14.137-1.976-19.152-6.765
        c-4.408-4.256-7.145-11.097-7.145-19.077c0.076-15.201,10.564-26.449,27.741-26.449c5.929,0,10.641,1.368,12.769,2.356
        l-1.596,5.396c-2.736-1.216-6.156-2.204-11.325-2.204c-12.464,0-20.597,7.752-20.597,20.597c0,12.997,7.752,20.673,19.761,20.673
        c4.333,0,7.297-0.608,8.816-1.368V36.466h-10.412v-5.32h16.873V55.771z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M373.136,41.938l-5.244,16.113h-6.916l17.48-51.227h7.904l17.481,51.227h-7.068l-5.473-16.113H373.136z M389.933,36.77
        l-5.016-14.745c-1.141-3.344-1.9-6.384-2.66-9.349h-0.229c-0.684,3.04-1.52,6.156-2.508,9.272l-5.017,14.821H389.933z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M411.288,7.509c3.42-0.684,8.209-1.064,12.769-1.064c7.068,0,11.629,1.292,14.821,4.18c2.508,2.28,4.028,5.776,4.028,9.729
        c0,6.765-4.257,11.249-9.653,13.073v0.152c3.952,1.444,6.309,5.168,7.524,10.413c1.673,7.22,2.889,12.084,3.952,14.061h-6.84
        c-0.836-1.444-1.977-5.853-3.42-12.237c-1.521-6.992-4.257-9.729-10.261-9.957h-6.232v22.193h-6.688V7.509z M417.977,30.842h6.765
        c7.068,0,11.553-3.876,11.553-9.729c0-6.688-4.789-9.5-11.781-9.577c-3.268,0-5.472,0.304-6.536,0.608V30.842z"/>
    <path class="map animate" d="M460.915,41.938l-5.244,16.113h-6.916l17.48-51.227h7.904l17.481,51.227h-7.068l-5.473-16.113H460.915z M477.712,36.77
        l-5.016-14.745c-1.141-3.344-1.9-6.384-2.66-9.349h-0.229c-0.684,3.04-1.52,6.156-2.508,9.272l-5.017,14.821H477.712z"/>

</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

animation just drawing using stroke, not using fill..

can you help me, how to make animate drawing svg with fill, not using stoke (without stroke)

Comment: What exactly would a fill animation look like? Stroke has a starting position and draws round a shape, fill just fills it so there's no starting/ending point.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it may be of interest  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32858946/1926369

Comment: @Royson, I have a hard time understanding why anyone would put a bounty on an unclear question. It's unclear what the outcome should be and why animating fill over stroke would be beneficial.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I am trying to do something that is similar to the question above. The only solution to this that I have found is to use Inkscape and create the SVG path from it and then use the path. I want something that can work with various fonts.

Answer (score 3):

As Robert said, you will need to explain what you mean by "animating the fill".  There are many ways you could do it.

But perhaps something like the following is what you were after?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <style>
            .map {
           fill: none;
              stroke: #FFF;
              stroke-dasharray: 500;
              stroke-dashoffset: 500;
            }
            .animate {
              -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
              animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
              -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            }
            @keyframes dash {
                from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 500; fill: #FFF !important;
                    fill: black;
                }
                to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0; fill: #FFF !important;
                    fill: white;
                }
            } 
            @-webkit-keyframes dash {
                from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
                    fill: black;
                }
                to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                    fill: white;
                }
            }               
 </style>
</head>
<body style="background: black;">

<svg id="ps4" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" viewBox="0 0 600 318" enable-background="new 0 0 600 318" xml:space="preserve">

 <path class="map animate" d="M5.831,7.433C9.023,6.9,13.355,6.444,18.599,6.444c6.537,0,11.325,1.521,14.365,4.256
  c2.736,2.432,4.484,6.156,4.484,10.792c0,4.712-1.368,8.361-3.952,11.021C30,36.238,24.3,38.138,17.991,38.138
  c-2.128,0-4.104-0.152-5.472-0.38v20.293H5.831V7.433z M12.519,32.362c1.064,0.304,3.268,0.456,5.472,0.456
  c7.98,0,12.845-3.952,12.845-10.944c0-6.917-4.788-10.185-12.084-10.185c-2.964,0-5.092,0.228-6.232,0.456V32.362z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M46.263,7.509c3.42-0.684,8.208-1.064,12.769-1.064c7.068,0,11.629,1.292,14.821,4.18c2.508,2.28,4.028,5.776,4.028,9.729
  c0,6.765-4.256,11.249-9.652,13.073v0.152c3.952,1.444,6.308,5.168,7.524,10.413c1.672,7.22,2.888,12.084,3.952,14.061h-6.84
  c-0.836-1.444-1.976-5.853-3.42-12.237c-1.52-6.992-4.256-9.729-10.26-9.957h-6.232v22.193h-6.688V7.509z M52.951,30.842h6.764
  c7.068,0,11.553-3.876,11.553-9.729c0-6.688-4.788-9.5-11.781-9.577c-3.268,0-5.472,0.304-6.536,0.608V30.842z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M93.838,6.825v51.227H87.15V6.825H93.838z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M148.636,35.554c-0.456-7.068-0.912-15.733-0.836-22.042h-0.228c-1.748,5.929-4.028,12.845-6.536,19.685l-8.893,24.549
  h-5.244l-8.133-24.397c-2.508-7.221-4.484-13.833-5.852-19.837h-0.228c-0.228,6.309-0.456,14.821-0.988,22.573l-1.368,21.965
  h-6.309l3.572-51.227h8.437l8.74,24.853c2.128,6.156,3.8,12.237,5.092,17.557h0.228c1.292-5.168,3.116-11.173,5.472-17.633
  l9.121-24.777h8.437l3.192,51.227h-6.537L148.636,35.554z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M174.018,41.938l-5.244,16.113h-6.917l17.481-51.227h7.905l17.481,51.227h-7.068l-5.473-16.113H174.018z M190.814,36.77
  l-5.016-14.745c-1.14-3.344-1.9-6.384-2.66-9.349h-0.228c-0.684,3.04-1.52,6.156-2.508,9.272l-5.017,14.821H190.814z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M228.357,58.051V6.825h7.373l16.341,25.841c3.724,6.08,6.764,11.477,9.196,16.721l0.152-0.076
  c-0.608-6.841-0.76-13.073-0.76-20.978V6.825h6.232v51.227h-6.688l-16.265-25.993c-3.572-5.701-6.993-11.553-9.577-17.101
  l-0.228,0.076c0.38,6.46,0.532,12.617,0.532,21.129v21.889H228.357z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M304.89,34.034h-19.837v18.545h22.193v5.472h-28.882V6.825h27.741v5.472h-21.053v16.265h19.837V34.034z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M354.746,55.771c-2.965,1.064-8.816,2.813-15.733,2.813c-7.752,0-14.137-1.976-19.152-6.765
  c-4.408-4.256-7.145-11.097-7.145-19.077c0.076-15.201,10.564-26.449,27.741-26.449c5.929,0,10.641,1.368,12.769,2.356
  l-1.596,5.396c-2.736-1.216-6.156-2.204-11.325-2.204c-12.464,0-20.597,7.752-20.597,20.597c0,12.997,7.752,20.673,19.761,20.673
  c4.333,0,7.297-0.608,8.816-1.368V36.466h-10.412v-5.32h16.873V55.771z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M373.136,41.938l-5.244,16.113h-6.916l17.48-51.227h7.904l17.481,51.227h-7.068l-5.473-16.113H373.136z M389.933,36.77
  l-5.016-14.745c-1.141-3.344-1.9-6.384-2.66-9.349h-0.229c-0.684,3.04-1.52,6.156-2.508,9.272l-5.017,14.821H389.933z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M411.288,7.509c3.42-0.684,8.209-1.064,12.769-1.064c7.068,0,11.629,1.292,14.821,4.18c2.508,2.28,4.028,5.776,4.028,9.729
  c0,6.765-4.257,11.249-9.653,13.073v0.152c3.952,1.444,6.309,5.168,7.524,10.413c1.673,7.22,2.889,12.084,3.952,14.061h-6.84
  c-0.836-1.444-1.977-5.853-3.42-12.237c-1.521-6.992-4.257-9.729-10.261-9.957h-6.232v22.193h-6.688V7.509z M417.977,30.842h6.765
  c7.068,0,11.553-3.876,11.553-9.729c0-6.688-4.789-9.5-11.781-9.577c-3.268,0-5.472,0.304-6.536,0.608V30.842z"/>
 <path class="map animate" d="M460.915,41.938l-5.244,16.113h-6.916l17.48-51.227h7.904l17.481,51.227h-7.068l-5.473-16.113H460.915z M477.712,36.77
  l-5.016-14.745c-1.141-3.344-1.9-6.384-2.66-9.349h-0.229c-0.684,3.04-1.52,6.156-2.508,9.272l-5.017,14.821H477.712z"/>

</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your participant Mr.Paul..

but, when drawing, i want to use fill,  not stroke and... so, could you help me for make that..?

Comment: You need to explain how you want the fill to animate.  What should it look like?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I believe I'm looking for something similar to Made Taman.  I want the `fill` attribute to draw itself in the way that the stroes do in your animation.  The stroke offset animation allows it to look like someone else is drawing the lines.  With fill, the animation is only on opacity.  Is it possible to "fade in" the fill bit by bit?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779906/how-to-animate-handwriting-text-on-the-web-page-using-svg