# Svg path fill with animation

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I have a path which is similar to circle. The task is to fill the path with a color with animation. The fill animation should be in circle manner and not from top to bottom or bottom to top.

my svg code is :

```html
<svg id="svg_circle" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox = '0 0 450 400'>
    <g class="svg_circle" transform = "translate(0,0)">
        <path class="path" stroke="#F0F0F0" fill="#fff" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="m-0.25,238.11061l88.59461,-82.21665l87.56445,86.40604l-33.99561,0.52367c2.72107,17.03346 46.55824,67.96739 105.37633,63.99055c70.95792,-4.79765 101.17847,-64.19902 103.74816,-97.50561c7.13262,-92.44812 -81.66575,-121.29229 -115.80064,-115.90062c-119.13463,18.8176 -96.38311,112.29843 -96.38311,112.29843l-50.54082,-49.76652l-46.48973,43.1249c-12.30406,-104.7234 83.23188,-194.53124 191.25985,-198.17803c97.87838,-3.30416 202.62703,53.17701 213.76024,178.57248c16.06879,180.98587 -165.14043,220.64431 -208.6094,218.37164c-143.15297,-7.48456 -189.38275,-115.91408 -199.33787,-158.14925l-39.14646,-1.57102z" id="svg_1">
            <animate id="project_anim1" attributeName="fill" from="#fff" to="#4DAF4C" begin="1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean by "in circle manner".  Perhaps add an image or two to show what you mean.

Comment: the fill should happen similar to loader as given in the link  http://codepen.io/AitorAlejandro/pen/KVxPEy  and it should freeze after the fill completes one time

Comment: Do you mean you want the fill to sweep around the circle like the hand of a clock?

Comment: that is what i exactly want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common "dasharray" line drawing technique would work for you, in combination with using the arrow shape as a mask.

[This technique is described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779906/how-to-animate-handwriting-text-on-the-web-page-using-svg)

However, since the head of your arrow shape overlaps the tail, to get a "perfect" result, you may have to divide the sweep into two parts. You would draw the tail part with a tail mask, and then the second half of the shape (including the arrow head) with a separate mask.

Here's a rough imperfect version showing the technique.

```html
<svg id="svg_circle" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox = '0 0 450 400'>
  <defs>
    <path id="arrow" stroke="#F0F0F0" fill="none" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="m-0.25,238.11061l88.59461,-82.21665l87.56445,86.40604l-33.99561,0.52367c2.72107,17.03346 46.55824,67.96739 105.37633,63.99055c70.95792,-4.79765 101.17847,-64.19902 103.74816,-97.50561c7.13262,-92.44812 -81.66575,-121.29229 -115.80064,-115.90062c-119.13463,18.8176 -96.38311,112.29843 -96.38311,112.29843l-50.54082,-49.76652l-46.48973,43.1249c-12.30406,-104.7234 83.23188,-194.53124 191.25985,-198.17803c97.87838,-3.30416 202.62703,53.17701 213.76024,178.57248c16.06879,180.98587 -165.14043,220.64431 -208.6094,218.37164c-143.15297,-7.48456 -189.38275,-115.91408 -199.33787,-158.14925l-39.14646,-1.57102z" id="svg_1"/>
    <clipPath id="arrow-clip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <use xlink:href="#arrow"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g clip-path="url(#arrow-clip)">
    <circle cx="244" cy="200" r="158" transform="rotate(-164,244,200)"
            fill="none" stroke="#4DAF4C" stroke-width="175"
            stroke-dasharray="993 993">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="993" to="0" begin="1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
    </circle>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#arrow"/>
</svg>
```

Here we are animating a really thick green line, but using your shape as a clipping path so it conforms to the shape you want.

But as I mentioned, the section where the head overlaps the end of the tail is not perfect, so you may need to divide the animation into two parts as described above.

Comment: Thanks and is there any way to mask then as similar to the image

Comment: My example uses your shape as a clipPath.

Comment: I have changed my path values as shown in the link and i want it to be filled with any gradient. Can you help https://jsfiddle.net/RandyRam/76bruw9j/

Comment: Use the technique I have shown you. You will need two copies of the animated circle. Clip one with the top half of the arrow, and the other with the bottom half of the arrow.

Comment: I have no idea about the clip concept can you make it and post the code

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. I have given you 90% of the solution. The rest is very simple. If you want to hire me to finish it, contact me via my profile.