# Fill Missing Part of SVG, Image

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, gsap

I have an image:

[image]

and I want to fill the missing part of it. The best way I found was to convert the missing part of the image to SVG and then start filling the missing part using tweenmax. For reference, I have added the animation for filling the svg but it is not animating like what I need i.e. it is increasing from center point. I need to blend the animation like the image missing area is filling from one end.
I can change the way of animating if there is any other way we can fill the missing part of the image?

```js
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var tween = new TimelineMax().to(".clip", 1, {
  attr: {
    width: 40
  }
}, "start")

// build scene
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  offset: 40
}).setTween(tween).addTo(controller);
```

```css
.svg_pos,
.pos4 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.svg_pos {
  left: 53px;
  top: -8px;
}

.dummy-cont {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  top: 300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>

<span class="pos4">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mkJDmQ/g.png" />
  <p class="svg_pos">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px"
width="0px" height="29.841px" viewBox="0 0 40.434 29.841" enable-background="new 0 0 40.434 29.841" xml:space="preserve" class="clip">
      <path fill="red" id="word" d="M13.806,0.657c0,0,5.724-0.982,12.366-0.544
c6.671,0.439,14.261,2.298,14.261,2.298L25.056,22.227c0,0-6.318,0.749-12.559,2.531C6.428,26.491,0.436,29.252,0.08,29.761
C-1.22,31.618,13.806,0.657,13.806,0.657z"/>
    </svg>
  </p>
</span>

<div class="dummy-cont"></div>
```

Comment: Make a `<mask>` or a `<clipPath>` for the "holes" in your shape.  Then you can animate the fill however you like and the mask will only show the parts you want.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779906/how-to-animate-handwriting-text-on-the-web-page-using-svg) has useful information that may help you.