# Animating path of Vector Drawable in Android

Tags: android, svg, android-animation

I'm trying to animate my exported SVG file from illustrator in my Android app by animating the line or path of character to show to the users how to properly write a character(ex: Japanese & Chinese character). But when I run the application, it only animates the edge/stroke of a character and brings back to its original state. Does anyone has already experienced this case before?

Here is my SVG drawable

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:width="300dp"
     android:height="300dp"
     android:viewportWidth="300.0"
     android:viewportHeight="300.0">
 <path
     android:name="invertu"
     android:fillColor="#FF000000"
     android:pathData="M21.23,263.43c0.68,-14.76 6.03,-28.9 
9.58,-43.12c3.82,-15.3 6.51,-30.8 10.68,-46.04c4.22,-15.46 9.06,-30.74 
14.02,-45.97c3.7,-11.38 7.53,-22.54 14.07,-32.66c14.19,-21.95 43.47,-29.83 
67.74,-33.8c13.6,-2.22 27.52,-2.66 41.27,-2.32c10.71,0.27 21.44,2.13 
31.29,6.5c28.73,12.76 43.98,42.42 53.04,70.95c5.67,17.85 9,36.29 
12.31,54.69c4.36,24.27 7.8,48.7 8.3,73.39c0.19,9.66 15.19,9.68
 15,0c-0.65,-32.46 -6.33,-64.51 -12.34,-96.33c-4.07,-21.5 -9.94,-42.7
 -19.22,-62.57c-8.76,-18.76 -21.57,-35.7 -38.92,-47.24c-20.15,-13.41 
-44.1,-15.18 -67.61,-14.26c-24.9,0.97 -49.66,5.88 -72.26,16.55c-20.76,9.8 
-33.38,26.41 -41.69,47.37c-4.61,11.65 -8.1,23.81 -11.83,35.77c-4.22,13.53 
-8.13,27.16 -11.53,40.92c-3.27,13.2 -5.45,26.61 -9.05,39.73c-3.47,12.65 
-7.23,25.26 -7.84,38.45C5.79,273.11 20.79,273.06 21.23,263.43L21.23,263.43z"
     android:strokeLineCap="round"
     android:strokeLineJoin="round"
     android:strokeWidth="3"
     android:trimPathEnd="0"/> </vector>
```

and this is my animated vector

```
<animated-vector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
  android:drawable="@drawable/ic_ba">

  <target android:name="invertu">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
        android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>
```

The VSG that I've exported from Adobe Illustrator becomes transparent in the center, only the outline animates from one point to another end.
[image: Vector Path]
TIA

Answer (score 1):

`trimPathStart` and `trimPathEnd` are intended to only set the start and end of the stroke (outline) of the path.  If you want the filled part of the path to be animated you'll have to do it another way.

If the line shapes in your characters have a constant width, then just draw them as a thick line - rather than an outline like it is now.  If you do that, the lines will be able to be animated using the trimPath method.

Comment: Yes I draw it as a solid line but when i impoted it to amdroid it becomes transparent, I wonder if it something related to illustrator settings or android studio itself

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: Hi, please see the attached image of vector preview from the android studio on my question. The vector drawable should be solid as it exported from Illustrator but when I imported it to the android studio, it becomes transparent at the center and it only rendering the outline.

Comment: As I said, if you want to use the trimPathEnd method of animating a line draw, then your path needs to be a single line from start point to end point. An outlined shape like yours won't work. If you need the line to have variable thickness, then you will need to use a different method. [You may have to switch to a WebView and use SVG and Javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779906/how-to-animate-handwriting-text-on-the-web-page-using-svg) Or you could reproduce the same technique using Android Canvas calls.