# Animate Vector Asset Path in Android (Line , Arc ,...)

Tags: android, animation, svg, vector

Assuming that I have a Line and I want Animate this Line , First of all Line is Hidden , After Time Passing Little by Little Line is Appear and Completed , My Question is It's Possible to do this in Android or I must use Adobe After Effect?
Update :

```
<svg 
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 500 400">     

<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;
    stroke:#009CA7;
    stroke-width:7;
    stroke-linecap:round;
    stroke-linejoin:round;
    stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
   <path class="st0" d="M10,140 C10,90,70,20,140,20 s110,40,110,40"/>
   <path class="st0" d="M210,260 l-1,-120 c0,-30,-30,-60,-70,-60 s-70,25,-70,60 v240"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**AnimateVectorDrawable using trimPath* attributes**

VectorDrawable `<path>` elements have three attributes that let you specify which portion of the path should be drawn.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html

> `android:trimPathStart`
>
> The fraction of the path to trim from the start, in the range from 0
>   to 1. Default is 0.
>
> `android:trimPathEnd`
>
> The fraction of the path to trim from the end, in the range from 0 to
>   1. Default is 1.
>
> `android:trimPathOffset`
>
> Shift trim region (allows showed region to include the start and end),
>   in the range from 0 to 1. Default is 0.

All you need to do is create an [`AnimatedVectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) that animates one or more of these attributes.  Most likely, you will only need to animate `trimPathEnd`.

If you don't want to create the `AnimatedVectorDrawable` file yourself, there are a few libraries to help with that. For example: https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath

**Path tracing**

Or if you want to work from an SVG, you could use the technique described by Romain Guy.

http://www.curious-creature.com/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/

There are also libraries that do the heavy lifting for you: 
 Eg. https://github.com/geftimov/android-pathview

Comment: thank you for answering me, after hours left of post this question i find this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37787761/8270271 although you ansering that question too, i have some arc path and i don't have an idea how to animate them , i will update my question

Comment: thank you again , i realized that to use trimPathEnd ;)