# Animate Circle logo using JS or SVG and css

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have a circle logo, and I'm trying to animate it like this example: https://codepen.io/sergiopedercini/pen/aWawra

```css
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.circle {
  stroke: #4CC790;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
     <path class="circle"
       stroke-dasharray="60, 100"
       d="M18 2.0845
       a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
       a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
     />
    </svg>
```

How can I do this?

This is my SVG image:

[image]

Comment: The Codepen and your code - when converted into a runnable Snippet - seem to animate the same way. What is your code supposed to do? What is it not doing?

Answer (score 1):

To start the animation from the position as in the picture, you need to change the `stroke-dasharray ="80, 20 "` and add
`stroke-dashoffset ="-20 "`

I hope this is what you need.

```css
.circular-chart {
display: block;
margin: 10px auto;
max-width: 80%;
max-height: 250px;
}

.circle {
stroke: #F29105;
fill: none;
stroke-width: 2.8;
stroke-linecap: round;
animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
0% {
stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
 <path  class="circle"
   stroke-dasharray="80, 20"
   stroke-dashoffset="-20"
   
   d="M18 2.0845
   a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
   a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
 />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandr_TT gave you a good answer. 
This is mine and it's different: I'm animating the `stroke-dashoffset`

Initially the `.circle` has `stroke-dasharray:100;`and `stroke-dashoffset:100;`: tyhe stroke is not visible. 
If you want to see 70% of the path's stroke you will need to animate the `stroke-dashoffset` to be 30 at the end of the animation (100 - 70 = 30).

```
@keyframes progress {
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 30;
    }
    }
```

This is an working example:

```css
.circular-chart {
display: block;
margin: 10px auto;
max-width: 20vw;
max-height: 20vw;

border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.circle {
stroke: #F29105;
fill: none;
stroke-width: 2.8;
stroke-linecap: round;
stroke-dasharray:100;
stroke-dashoffset:100;
animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
100% {
stroke-dashoffset: 30;
}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
 <circle r="15.9155" cx="18" cy="18" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>
 <path  class="circle" 
   d="M18 2.0845
   A15.9155 15.9155 0 0 0 18 33.9155
   A15.9155 15.9155 0 0 0 18 2.0845"
 /> 
</svg>
```

Also please read this article at CSS-tricks to learn more about [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

Comment: You have a classic approach and explanations are given at a high level. I tried to give a concise answer with a minimum of copyright code changes

Comment: You are both ignoring the fact that OPs shape is clearly not a simple circular path. :)

Answer (score 0):

The animation technique you are trying to use works only on unfilled lines.

Your SVG is (presumably) a filled outlined shape.  The standard technique won't work for that.  You need to use a modified approach.

Have a look at the following answer for an approach that should work for you:
[How to animate handwriting text on the web page using SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779906/how-to-animate-handwriting-text-on-the-web-page-using-svg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is math solution, it is not so difficult to calculate arc points in every frame:

```js
let r1 = 90, r2 = 60, r3 = 20;

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(t) {
  let a = -t/300 - Math.PI/2;
  let s = Math.sin(a);
  let c = Math.cos(a);
  let largeArc = c < 0 ? 0 : 1;
  t < 1.4e3 && requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  path.setAttribute('d', `
    M0,${-r1}
    A${r1},${r1},0,${largeArc},0,${c*r1},${s*r1}
    A${r3},${r3},0,0,0,${c*r2},${s*r2}
    A${r2},${r2},0,${largeArc},1,0,${-r2}
    A${r3},${r3},0,0,0,0,${-r1}
  `);
}
```

```css
body { margin:0;overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-100,-100,200,200 height=100vh>
  <path id=path fill="#f29105"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: I think this is the closest results to it. if i want increase the speed what should i do ?

Comment: `t/600` decrease denominator here

Comment: This will increase the circle rotation.