# How can I make svg animation like gif?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, loading, ellipse

How to make svg animation like gif? Help..

[GIF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEnEG.gif)

[PNG Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5H11.png)

```
svg link : https://codepen.io/ysw/pen/OJvQXGz
```

Comment: by animating the SVG in your desired way - have you written any code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Learn SMIL.. And there is this fantastic tool called [Google](https://google.com) that answers all your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use svg path fill animation using CSS like

```css
.line {
  stroke-dasharray: 280 280;
  stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path class="line" d="M 10,75 L 290,75" stroke="green" stroke-width="50"/>
</svg>
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779906/how-to-animate-handwriting-text-on-the-web-page-using-svg)